# Loading 3 column csv as list of tuplets

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, machine-learning

I have a CSV file with 3 columns and 80 rows. I want to load them as following list of tuplet. Is that possible with pandas?

`results = [((55.5,69.5),1),((71,81.5),1),.....]`

results.csv

```
X0 |   X1  | Y  
55.5| 69.5 | 1  
71  | 81.5 | 1  
.....
```

Comment: Can't you just load it with plain Python code, either a file read and split, or with the help of the `csv` module?  The file format looks simple, but your desired result is a bit unusual - easier to make from scratch than via `pandas`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, a list comprehension is all you need:

```
df = pd.read_csv('your_file_here.csv', sep='[\s\|]+')
results = [(a,b) for a,b in zip(zip(df['X0'],df['X1']), df['Y'])]
```

Output:

```
[((55.5, 69.5), 1), ((71.0, 81.5), 1)]
```

Comment: Thanks but where do  I provide file input ? in your statement above ?

Comment: @PitDigger Updated.

Answer (score 2):

You could do:

```
result = list(zip(df[['X0','X1']].itertuples(index=False, name=None), df['Y']))
print(result)
```

**Output**

```
[((55.5, 69.5), 1), ((71.0, 81.5), 1)]
```

Answer (score 2):

```
In [595]: txt="""X0 | X1 | Y 
     ...: 55.5| 69.5 | 1 
     ...: 71 | 81.5 | 1"""
```

using numpy

```
In [597]: data = np.genfromtxt(txt.splitlines(), delimiter='|',skip_header=1,dty
     ...: pe=[('X',[('X0',float),('X1',float)]),('Y',int)])                     
In [598]: data                                                                  
Out[598]: 
array([((55.5, 69.5), 1), ((71. , 81.5), 1)],
      dtype=[('X', [('X0', '<f8'), ('X1', '<f8')]), ('Y', '<i8')])
```

as list

```
In [599]: data.tolist()                                                         
Out[599]: [((55.5, 69.5), 1), ((71.0, 81.5), 1)]
```